# HTML marquee not working after fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a progress bar with html marquee. when user click submit, `fadeIn` the HTML marquee and fadeOut with ajax success. But when i click the submit button marquee will `fadeIn` and not working. here is my try:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#signup-submit').click(function(){
  $('.bar').fadeIn();
 })

})
```

```css
.bar{
  background:#a0a0a0;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  display:none;
}
.progressing{
  width:50px;
  height:4px;
  background:orangered;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee class="bar" scrollamount=50><div class="progressing"></div></marquee>
<input type="button" id="signup-submit" value="signup"/>
```

But when without any jquery function it is working

```css
.bar{
  background:#a0a0a0;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
.progress{
  width:50px;
  height:4px;
  background:red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="bar" scrollamount=50><div class="progress"></div> </marquee>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you using a `<marquee>` for this? We have a perfectly good `<progress>` element now.

Comment: @AuxTaco But HTML5 not working in `<IE9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its because of `display:none` that the marquee is not working, instead go with setting `opacity:0` and `height:0px`, Please refer the below snippet demonstrating the approach!

Please use the same approach for hiding the marquee element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#signup-submit').click(function(){
  $('.bar').addClass("hide");
 })

})
```

```css
.bar{
  background:#a0a0a0;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  opacity:0;
  height:0px;
  transition:opacity 1s ease; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
.bar.hide{
  opacity:1;
  height:auto;
}
.progressing{
  width:50px;
  height:4px;
  background:orangered;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee class="bar" scrollamount=50><div class="progressing"></div></marquee>
<input type="button" id="signup-submit" value="signup"/>
```